# How to set user data to a custom RGBA color code

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, rgba

I'm working with JavaFX and scene builder and want to know how to set a radio button to display a certain color by the RGBA color code.

I know if I want to display a color such as blue I would write

```
blueRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLUE);
```

However, say I want to enter the color: Red to be 100, Green to be 40, Blue to be 70, and Alpha to be 0.4

How would I assign that to a color? Would it be something like this?

```
int R = 100;
int G = 40;
int B = 70;
float A = 0.4;
customRadioButton.setUserData(Color.RGBA);
```

Comment: [`Color.rbg(100, 40, 70, 0.4)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#rgb(int,int,int,double)).

Comment: _Correction:_ `rgb`*